# Can I get the start-up arguments in Neutralinojs?

Tags: neutralinojs

I'm trying go make an application able to run a file type, I want to get the path to the file which the user opened the app with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NL_CWD` to get the current working directory. See more information about Neutralinojs global variables [here](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/#/gettingstarted/quickstart?id=neutralino-super-globals).